# Hotkey for toggling between vertex/edge/face select modes in Edit Mode?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, shortcut

In *Edit Mode*, in the 3D View, is there a hotkey for toggling between vertex/edge/face editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe its Ctr + tab then choose from the menu that pops up.

Answer (score 1):

In **Blender 2.79** and before (not sure how long back), the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> indeed opened a menu to choose the selection type, one had to be in edit mode first though.
[image]

From **Blender 2.8** on wards, there are the following hot keys while in **Edit Mode**:

<kbd>1</kbd> for **Vertex** select
<kbd>2</kbd> for **Edge** select
<kbd>3</kbd> for **Face** select

You can add multiple active modes by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing one of the 3 keys, allowing to activate all 3 at once if so desired.
Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the other hand, when pressing <kbd>2</kbd> for example would limit the selection mode to the edge selection again, regardless which selection mode(s) was/were selected before.

Other then the direct hotkeys (not sure why the specific hotkeys are not shown), the information regarding the use of <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> can also be found by hovering over the icon for the selection modes.
[image]

This is based on the default installation of Blender 2.8+ addons can and have changed those hotkeys.
Should there be an issue with the default hotkeys, it's recommended to first go in the **Blender Preferences** and look under **Keymap** and search for <kbd>1</kbd>.
In the **Mesh** section we find the **Edit Mode** related hotkeys:
[image]
*marked red the important parts for in this case the vertex selection key-bind*

Comment: Thank you so much, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

@Xylvier's method works best if you have a numpad section on your keyboard.

However, as a corollary, for those who are 1) on laptop using the emulated numpad and 2) like single, but not mixed modes, you can just set the first three by pressing, say Ctrl-1, -2 or -3 for these (or Shift-1, etc) as he shows for the existing 1, 2, and 3.

Normally, for most software, as he points out, Ctrl is use for toggling a feature.  Shift is for adding. But, for those of us who like single mode (vertex, edge or face - but not more than one mode) you simple use one of these prefixes for making this a unique keystroke.

The reason you use the prefix is so you don't mess with the views (you probably emulated 1 is for X, 3 for Y, etc).  Also, you probably don't want to "fix" the ones farther down in the list if you don't like to have more than one edit mode selected - they work in the sense that the don't do anything, since you don't have a numpad. That is, the ones with the extended and expand check boxes are probably what you don't want - unless you really want to try using the mouse to do multiple modes.

Hopefully useful for those of us on Macbooks that like the old single mode method.